# Clarification on a problem found in Lang's algebra

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Here is the problem:

> Suppose $f(x) \in k[x]$ is monic and has distinct roots in some splitting field. If these roots form a field then show that the characteristic of $k$ is $p$ and that $f(x) = x^{p^n} - x$.

What I basically did I said let $F = \{r  : f(r) = 0\}$, where $r$ is a root in this splitting field. Then $F$ is a finite field, by hypothesis so the characteristic of $F$ is $p$ some prime, and $F^\times$ is cyclic. In particular, $|F^\times| = p^n - 1$, for some integer $n \geq 1$. By Lagrange theorem, $x \in F$ satisfies $|x| \mid  |F^\times|$which after a bit of manipulation shows you that $x^{p^n} - x = 0$. Since every root of $f$ is in $F$, this means $f(x) = x^{p^n} - x$, as desired.

**Questions** What I'm strugling to understand is (1) where we used that the roots were attained in the splitting field. It seems like I could have just replaced this with algebraic closure and been fine, but then the result seems absurd. So it is possible that my proof is wrong or I'm misunderstanding something. (2) I also don't know how to show the second part that the characteristic of $k$ is $p$? Hint here would be great.

Comment: (1)I think the splitting field is just to make some order. As you say, it could as well had been in an algebraic closure, though I don't understand why then you think the result is absurd...(2) You already showed in your proof's second line the field is finite and thus its characteristic is a prime $\;p\;$ ...!

Comment: The key is really that they are distinct. You could have $f(x)=(x^{p^n}-x)^m$, if they were not required to be distinct roots.

Comment: @DonAntonio I showed that $F$ has characteristic $p$. What I was missing is the argument that so too must $k$. But as mentioned by Eric Wofsey, this immediately gives the result since subfields of a field share the same characteristic. Suppose not, then the characteristic of the subfield can be only smaller. But now embed this element in the larger field, giving a contradiction (use the inclusion homomorphism, for example). So $F$ and $k$ have the same characteristic as the splitting field, so in particular $F$ and $k$ also share the same characteristic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (1) where we used that the roots were attained in the splitting field. It seems like I could have just replaced this with algebraic closure and been fine, but then the result seems absurd.

The splitting field is not important here at all; it's just a place for the roots to live so we can talk about them.  The argument works perfectly well if you instead take the roots of $f$ in any field over which $f$ splits, including an algebraic closure of $k$.  I don't know what you think is "absurd" about this.

> (2) I also don't know how to show the second part that the characteristic of $k$ is $p$?

Well, you know the characteristic of $F$ is $p$, and $k$ and $F$ are both subfields of a common field (the splitting field of $f$ over $k$).

Comment: you're right. The counterexamples I was thinking of critically lack the property that the roots form a field themselves.